# WPF: DependencyProperty refusing to work

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I'm trying to register 3 dependency properties on a Window to control it's formatting. I've looked over and over the code but I must be missing something.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextColor", typeof(Color), typeof(WinStickyFingers), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.White));
public Color TextColor {
    get { return (Color)base.GetValue(TextColorProperty); }
    set { base.SetValue(TextColorProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundColor", typeof(Color), typeof(WinStickyFingers), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Black));
public Color BackgroundColor {
    get { return (Color)base.GetValue(BackgroundColorProperty); }
    set {
        base.SetValue(BackgroundColorProperty, value);
    }
}    
<TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{Binding TextColor,Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}}" Background="{Binding Path=BackgroundColor}" />
```

I'm using Bea Stollnitz's debugging method but my breakpoint isn't even triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the `DataContext` of the `TextBlock`? How does it know that it is supposed to bind to the properties on your `Window`?

You need to either set `DataContext` to the `Window` instance, or set the `Source` (or `RelativeSource`, or `ElementName`) properties on your bindings. All of these properties exist as a means of resolving the bound object for your `Binding`. `DataContext` is a fallback if none of the others is set, but I'm guessing that you haven't set that either.

Comment: I was under the impression that the closest top level. Developing ASP.NET has polluted my mind ;)

Problem solved by setting RelativeSource on the parent container. Thanks.